# Using grep command to transfer data into a new file

Tags: bash, unix, grep

This might be super simple, but I have a `.txt` file with seismic data in which I'm trying to use the `grep` command to print out specific data only from Nevada (data in the file is marked either `CA` or `NV`) and to put it into its own `.txt` file.

Sample data:

```
map 0.2 2016/09/26 18:36:51 39.330N 119.991W 4.7 9 km ( 6 mi) N of Incline Village, NV 

map 1.5 2016/09/26 18:26:27 39.362N 122.781W 19.5 25 km (15 mi) NNE of Upper Lake, CA 

map 1.5 2016/09/26 18:18:16 36.055N 117.857W 2.2 8 km ( 5 mi) E of Coso Junction, CA 

map 0.2 2016/09/26 18:10:46 38.363N 118.324W 4.6 32 km (20 mi) SE of Hawthorne, NV
```

I'm typing: `grep NV filename > newfilename`

But nothing is showing up. What's wrong? (My homework is to specifically use the `grep` command.)

Comment: The result of `grep` depends on the file contents. But you don't show us the file contents, so we can't help you. Also, you've redirected `grep` output to `newfilename`, so don't expect to see something from `grep` in the standard output.

Comment: so...........................what should i do.................................

Comment: depends on what are you expecting to see and where. Do you expect to see the results of `grep` on the screen, or in the file? I'd expect a sample file contents in this post. Well, without sample contents, I can only say that the command `grep NV filename > newfilename` will search for strings containing `NV` substring in `filename` file and store the lines containing this substring in `newfilename` file. The strings will not be shown on the screen because of the redirect (`>`). So was it the behavior you expected, or what do you expect from the command?

Comment: I know it's not going to print to the terminal screen. i wanted to move the data points to a new file. but nothing is showing up on the new file

Comment: map 0.2 2016/09/26 18:36:51 39.330N 119.991W  4.7    9 km ( 6 mi) N   of Incline Village, NV

map 1.5 2016/09/26 18:26:27 39.362N 122.781W 19.5   25 km (15 mi) NNE of Upper Lake, CA

map 1.5 2016/09/26 18:18:16 36.055N 117.857W  2.2    8 km ( 5 mi) E   of Coso Junction, CA

map 0.2 2016/09/26 18:10:46 38.363N 118.324W  4.6   32 km (20 mi) SE  of Hawthorne, NV

Comment: This string contains `NV`. If `filename` contains this string, then `grep NV filename > newfilename` will put this string into `newfilename`, unless something goes wrong (for example, you have no permissions to write to this file etc.). In the latter case `grep` exits with non-zero status. You can check the status by checking the `$?` variable: `grep ....`, then `echo $?`.

Comment: grep NV *filename* > *newfilename* echo $?

Comment: as separate commands

Comment: Okay, it says 1

Comment: From the man page: _Normally the exit status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and  2 if  an  error occurred._ Look how it normally works [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/38b8737e02eca4f7ef1661a82f5cae6f).

Comment: do you get any output for `grep 'map' filename` ? just as a test, do you also get output for `sed -n '/NV/p' filename` ?

Comment: What output do you get if you do `grep -c "NV" filename`?

Comment: @Sundeep for the first, no output. and for the latter command i get this: sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence

Comment: @VarunM the output is "0"

Answer (score 1):

You want this:

```
  cat *filename* | grep something  > result.txt
```

Comment: Hmm, it creates the new file but there is nothing on it.

Comment: What are you trying to search for? cat *filename* will display the content of the file. Try that by itself first to make sure you are getting something

Comment: There is no use in `cat` here. `grep something *filename*` is the same as `cat *filename* | grep something`, except the latter forks an extra process. And did he ask about the shell expansion?

Comment: Ruslan, you bring a good point. I thought it is easier to narrow down the problem because each stage can be tested

Comment: the new filename i made was NVdata.txt and I typed cat NVdata.txt but nothing is printed to the screen. I tried it out for the initial data file cat SIO233_HW_1.txt and all the data was printed

Comment: Your NVdata.txt is empty then. Double check to make sure you have something in it

Answer (score 0):

Your command appears as though it should have worked, but for safety you would want to be sure you're getting exactly what you want.  Below grep would only get lines that end in NV

```
grep " NV$" filename > newfilename
```

When you say you can't see anything are you viewing the file contents afterward?

Comment: Yes, I can see that the new file is created but when I open it up it's blank.

Answer (score 0):

I copy/pasted your sample data into a file called `sample-data` and tried the `grep` pattern I would have used (`' NV$'`), but then I found only one line came through, the last one, because there was [invisible] whitespace after the `NV` in the first line.  So to guard against that, I put `[ \t]*` between the `NV` and the `$` (end of line symbol) in the grep pattern, and I got the result I expected.  See below:

```
$ grep ' NV$' sample-data > result.txt
$ cat result.txt
map 0.2 2016/09/26 18:10:46 38.363N 118.324W 4.6 32 km (20 mi) SE of Hawthorne, NV
$ cat sample-data
map 0.2 2016/09/26 18:36:51 39.330N 119.991W 4.7 9 km ( 6 mi) N of Incline Village, NV 

map 1.5 2016/09/26 18:26:27 39.362N 122.781W 19.5 25 km (15 mi) NNE of Upper Lake, CA 

map 1.5 2016/09/26 18:18:16 36.055N 117.857W 2.2 8 km ( 5 mi) E of Coso Junction, CA 

map 0.2 2016/09/26 18:10:46 38.363N 118.324W 4.6 32 km (20 mi) SE of Hawthorne, NV
$ grep ' NV[ \t]*$' sample-data > result.txt
$ cat result.txt
map 0.2 2016/09/26 18:36:51 39.330N 119.991W 4.7 9 km ( 6 mi) N of Incline Village, NV 
map 0.2 2016/09/26 18:10:46 38.363N 118.324W 4.6 32 km (20 mi) SE of Hawthorne, NV
$
```

In short, I think what you want, to be safe, is:

```
grep ' NV[ \t]*$' sample-data > result.txt
```

Or, even safer, if you don't trust there always to be a space between the comma and `NV`:

```
grep ',[ \t]*NV[ \t]*$' sample-data > result.txt
```

which, translated, means, "match lines that have a comma, zero or more spaces or tabs, NV, zero or more spaces or tabs, and nothing more before the end of the line."

By the way, if this is homework, and not for your job or home project, technically you should probably admit to your teacher that you asked for help on StackOverflow.  Your teacher will be more impressed with your honesty, and probably won't ding you if you can say, "I get it, I get it, look at these other examples I tested and they worked too!"  A teacher's main goal is that you learn and understand, not that you get some score.  My purpose in providing this answer is to help you understand a tiny bit more about `grep`, which millions of us use every single day in our lives to get our work done, so it really is worth learning.  Probably I should have provided a "teaching" example that was not the exact answer, but this was such a small, trivial problem I just answered it during my coffee break.  Just be honest with your teacher is all I ask.

Comment: I also answered it because I saw "seismic data" in the question, and I've worked with seismic data in several jobs over the years.

Comment: Thank you for this! I tell my professor all the time I get help from stackoverflow. I try to keep all my terminal windows open and show him my process. It was late at night and he's a busy man, and grep was driving me nuts especially because it seemed like such a simple command. Just wanted to understand what was going on, no worries about homework scores here!